# CORS fails, but CORS headers are present, error: Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: spring-boot, cors

I'm getting two errors in the dev panel in Chrome when trying to send a request to my spring back end. I have set up a CORS servlet filter to add the headers. The errors I get are:

```
main.7851a9cd.js:1 Error during service worker registration: 
DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed (see: tinyUrl removed).
(anonymous) @ main.7851a9cd.js:1
Promise rejected (async)
o @ main.7851a9cd.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.7851a9cd.js:1
/#/join:1 Failed to load http://ec2-54-148-176-27.us-west-
2.compute.amazonaws.com:8282/register_by_email: Request header field 
Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in 
preflight response.
```

My filter:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    log.debug("CORSFilter.doFilter()");
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    int len = dos.size();
    HttpServletRequest request= (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "180");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", ""+len);
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

The dev panel:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, I was able to get it working by adding all the headers that I see in the request to the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header in the response:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    log.debug("CORSFilter.doFilter() --");
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "180");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "User-Agent,Referer,Origin,Host,Connection,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Cache-Control,Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language");
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` is not yet supported. https://crbug.com/615313

Comment: Thanks, I removed that one, but still get `Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.` I see a Cache-Control header, but it must be added by spring, it's not in my cors filter.